# Struggling to make list stay on browser refresh

Tags: javascript

I managed to get the local storage to store the data for the list created and the array gets the stored local data.

What I need to do is make sure that the list stays on the browser when the browser is refreshed.

This is what I have done regarding render list with local storage

```
/*----Array with local Storage----*/

let budgetArray = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(BUDGETLIST_KEY) ?? "[]");
```

```
/*----Budget list Object----*/

function makeNewBudget(){
  const data = {
    id: createId(),
    cashflowNew: el.cashflow.value,
    catagoryNew: el.catagory.value,
    labelNew: el.label.value,
    dateNew: createdDate(),
    numberNew: el.number.value,
  };
  return data;
}
```

```
/*----Render Budget List----*/
function renderList(){

el.list.innerHTML = budgetArray.map(function (data,i) {

  return `<div class="entry">
  <div class="list">
    <button onclick="deleteItem(event, ${i})" class="Archive" data-id="${data.id}">
          <img src="../resources/Images/archive.png" alt="Archive">
      </button>
      <button onclick="editItem(event, ${i})" class = "edit" data-id="${data.id}" class = "edit" data-id="${data.id}">
          <img src="../resources/Images/edit.png" alt="Edit">
      </button>

      <div class="input" data-id="${data.id}"></div>
      <label class="dateNew">${data.dateNew}</label>
      <label class="cashflowNew">${data.cashflowNew}</label>
      <label class="catagoryNew">${data.catagoryNew}</label>
      <label class="labelNew">${data.labelNew}</label>
      <label class="numberNew">${data.numberNew}</label>
  </div>
</div>`
;
});

el.label.value="";
el.number.value="";

}
```

```
/*----form validation----*/
let budgetButton = document.querySelector(".budget-button");

let label = document.querySelector(".label");
let num = document.querySelector(".number");

budgetButton.addEventListener("click", () => {

  if (!label.value || !num.value) {
    alert("please make sure all inputs are filled");
  }
  
  budgetArray.push(makeNewBudget())

  renderList();

  storedEntry();

});
```

```
/*----Remove from array----*/
function deleteItem(event, i){
  budgetArray.splice(i, 1);

  storedEntry()

  renderList();
  
}
```

```
/*----Store Stored budget list----*/
function storedEntry(){
    window.localStorage.setItem(BUDGETLIST_KEY, JSON.stringify(budgetArray));
}
```

I think what I need to do is have the storage somehow in the `function renderList()`, I am not sure how exactly.

I tried this but does not work

```
function renderList(){

storedEntry()

el.list.innerHTML = budgetArray.map(function (data,i) {

  return `<div class="entry">
  <div class="list">
    <button onclick="deleteItem(event, ${i})" class="Archive" data-id="${data.id}">
          <img src="../resources/Images/archive.png" alt="Archive">
      </button>
      <button onclick="editItem(event, ${i})" class = "edit" data-id="${data.id}" class = "edit" data-id="${data.id}">
          <img src="../resources/Images/edit.png" alt="Edit">
      </button>

      <div class="input" data-id="${data.id}"></div>
      <label class="dateNew">${data.dateNew}</label>
      <label class="cashflowNew">${data.cashflowNew}</label>
      <label class="catagoryNew">${data.catagoryNew}</label>
      <label class="labelNew">${data.labelNew}</label>
      <label class="numberNew">${data.numberNew}</label>
  </div>
</div>`
;
});

el.label.value="";
el.number.value="";

}
```

Comment: I feel like you need more explanation of what you're doing and how it differs from what's happening. "does not work" is never good explanation. Note that `.map()` returns an array. Since you're creating an array of strings, you probably want to `.join()` the array before assigning it to `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the render function on `DOMContentLoaded` or `load`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  renderList()
})
```

**or**

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  renderList()
})
```